# Send a xml file with POST and receive in php

Tags: java, php, android

I'm working on an application using Android SO and Java. I would like to send an xml file as POST to a php server, that inserts the information from the xml into a database.

how can i do that?

regards :D

Comment: Are you asking how to send from the phone or how to set up the PHP to handle the incoming data?

Comment: how to handle de php to receive the xml sent by java...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to POST xml with Java

```
String urlText = "http://example.com/someservice.php";
String someXmlContent = "<root><node>Some text</node></root>";
try {
  HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlText).openConnection();
  c.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
  writer.write(someXmlContent);
  writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: u can tell me how i receive this post in php server ?

Answer (score 0):

Code to post XML from Java to PHP:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/xml.php"); //your php file on localhost
String document = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\<your xml file name>";
FileReader fr = new FileReader(document);
char[] buffer = new char[1024*10];
int bytes_read = 0;            
if((bytes_read = fr.read(buffer)) != -1){
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml");
    urlc.setDoOutput(true);
    urlc.setDoInput(true);
  //Now send xml data to your xml file
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(urlc.getOutputStream());
    pw.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
    pw.close();
 //Read response from php file
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();                
}
```

You may read more about `user.dir` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)
Code to read data from passed xml file through java in PHP

```
<?php
$dataPOST = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xmlData = simplexml_load_string($dataPOST);    
print_r($xmlData);
?>
```

Read more about `simplexml_load_string()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)
It will simply print xml data on web page as response.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, thanks for editing, now it looks much better!!!